# Во время сборки Generate Singed ошибка Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

Во время сборки Generate Singed Apk ошибка (ошибка на все PNG изображения в проекте, даже на ic_launcher.png, без PNG ресурсов **apk собирается**):

```
   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
    > Multiple task action failures occurred:
       > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
          > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #1: Unexpected error during compile 'E:\Android\test\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png', attempting to stop daemon.
            This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
       > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
          > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #2: Unexpected error during compile 'E:\Android\test\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png', attempting to stop daemon.
```

Android Studio 4.1
//project

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.test"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 8
            versionName '1.8'
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                shrinkResources true
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
}
```

// modules

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Отключение - не помогает.

```
shrinkResources true
minifyEnabled true
```

Invalidate Caches и Удаление папки .gradle - не помогает.

Помогает только изменение версии Android Gradle Plugin Version на 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант который как-то мне помог:

1. в `build.gradle` - `aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }`
2. удалить `C:\Users.gradle\caches`
3. ребут студии с очисткой кеша

у вас в ошибках идет речь о лого вашего приложения:

```
ic_launcher.png
ic_launcher_round.png
```

[вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712063/build-failing-during-merge-resources-with-android-gradle-plugin-3-3-0) речь идет о подобной проблеме. Думаю имеет смысл посмотреть что там с картинками, может вы их меняли и они не подтянулись. Так же можно почистить проект и перестроится.

Comment: Ошибка вообще на все PNG файлы(не только ЛОГО) aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false } - работает *apk собирается, но из за отключения "оптимизации" PNG - увеличился размер APK на 30%. Придётся использовать classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2', а не 4.1.0

Comment: Попробуйте перебрать версии градла как вариант, так же если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.